# LINQ Subquery in Where Clause returning error in LINQPad

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linqpad

While executing following query in LINQPad:

```
var innerquery = Bills.Where(e => e.id == 15);

var entity = Customer
    .Join(applications, cust => cust.cust_id, app => app.cust_id,
    (cust, app) => new { Customer = cust, application = app })

    .Join(advices, cust => cust.application.app_id, sa => sa.app_id,
    (cust, sa) => new { Customer = cust, advice = sa })

    .Where(x => x.advice.status_id == 4)
    .Where(e => innerquery.Any(a => a.com_id == e.advice.application.com_id)) // exception at this line
    .Where(e => innerquery.Any(a => a.fnd_id == e.advice.application.fnd_id))
    .Select(x => x.Customer.Customer.cust_id);

entity.Dump();
```

It ends with exception in the LINQPad:

**'LINQPad.User.appSancAdvice' does not contain a definition for 'application' and no extension method 'application' accepting a first argument of type 'LINQPad.User.appSancAdvice' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)**

The brief logic behind the scene is to select only customers

- having approved advices (status_id=4); and
- having records in application table with same committee (com_id) and fund (fnd_id) as of the specific bill's (innerquery)

- `customer` entity is related to `application`
- `application` entity is related to `advice`
- However, `application` entity is not related to `bill`

## Update

`(table structure)`

**customer**
cust_id

**application**
app_id
cust_id
com_id
fnd_id

**advice**
app_id
status_id

**bill**
bill_id
com_id
fnd_id

Comment: Might help to see the underlying table structure here.

Comment: @Moo-Juice please see in update above.

Comment: also - what does LinQPad's "SQL" result show in the resulting SQL?

Comment: @Moo-Juice as ends up with error it doesn't show resulting T-SQL.

Comment: it resolved. correct formation on that line should be `.Where(e => innerquery.Any(a => a.com_id == e.customer.application.com_id))`

Comment: however, i have still confusion in my mind about this error...! grateful, if someone could explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got resolved. Correct navigation route for the lines in error was:

```
.Where(e => innerquery.Any(a => a.com_id == e.customer.application.com_id)) // exception at this line
.Where(e => innerquery.Any(a => a.fnd_id == e.customer.application.fnd_id))
```

The error was due to `e.advice.application`